# How can I use an Android Spinner object to load other activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-spinner

i want a spinner when select an item from the spinner its should load the corresponding java page that has been set.can we  load a java page on selecting an item from spinner  in android if so how can we implement this can any one provide  some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] items ={“One”,“Two”,“Three”,“Four”,“Five”};

Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01); 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
      switch(position){
case 0:
//call first class
break;
case 1:
//call second class
break;
case 2:
//call third class
break;
case 3:
//call fourth class
break;
default:
break;
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
//nothing selected from spinner
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    switch(position) {
                                            //Use cases to set Intents
                                            } 


                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // Do Nothing
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

just use spinner.onItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener())

and in onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterview, View view, int position, long id) method body write your logic to start new activity based on the position.